# Why was Benjamin included with Judah?

Tags: yehuda, israel

When Israel was divided during the reign of Rehoboam, (2 Chronicles 10-11) why was Benjamin included with Judah instead of with the rest of the tribes?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Judah managed to retain control over Binyamin and the prophecy of the torn garment was written after.

Practical answer: The bait hamikdsah was in Benjamin. God didn't want to prevent the king of Judah from performing hakel. Also, Judah was God's first choice for kingship and if he took away the BHM, Judah would have been the one to set up the golden calves.

Theologically acceptable answer: Rehobam was crowned king of Judah and needed a separate coronation to be king of Israel. Even though Solomon had one country (not counting edon, moab, aram etc) there were distinct regions, just like the king of England is also the king of Scotland.

God was taking away his rule over Israel, not Judah, however, if he needed to let Rehobam keep a scrap so as not to extinguish the possibility of Judah regaining control over Israel.